# How to change the value of a variable from the fontend in PHP?

Tags: php, html, variables

I want to change the value of a variable from the front end. But I want this change permanently in file even if we reload this page the changed code should be executed. This is my code:

```
<?php $headingMain = 'Amazing Website'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP PRACTICES</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2><?php echo $headingMain; ?></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case I want to change `$headingMain` from front end.
**BUT HOW?**

Comment: Is database the one you are looking for?

Comment: i didnt get you actually,Could you please explain?

Comment: Im ot sure i understand what exactly you are asking.

Comment: Without database! If it's possible

Comment: I want to change this `$headingMain`'s value to something else but not from back end but instead from front end

Comment: So you need to `fopen()` the file and `fwrite()` on it. Search both functions.

Answer (score 1):

you should enter the data in to a database and load it from there when needed,
other solution would be to write it in a text file but i wouldn't recommend it.

: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php